# Windows Use SpeechRecognizer with UWP app in background

Tags: background, uwp, speech-recognition

I need to capture speech and convert it in text while user is using its computer.
I know "SpeechRecognizer" class in UWP and i've setupped an application that works if it is in "Active", but if you switch app (i.e. use browser) it doesn't capture speech.

How can i capture speech while user is using its pc?

Comment: Solved creating a WPF application and using SpeechRecognitionEngine (System.Speech) instead of SpeechRecognizer of UWP.

Comment: Hi Xavier,how can i mark my comment as answer?

Comment: You could make a reply as an answer and mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved creating a WPF application and using SpeechRecognitionEngine (System.Speech) instead of SpeechRecognizer of UWP

Answer (score 0):

Try [extended execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-minimized-with-extended-execution) which requests the OS to postpone the suspension of your app after it is switched to the background. In my test the `SpeechRecognizer` works well in an extended execution session.

The length of the extended execution depends on whether you are using desktop device or mobile device, and whether the device is connected to wall power or battery power, and other factors.

> If the device is connected to wall power, there is no limit to the length of the extended execution time period. (but system can revoke a session at any time, the doc has more detailed explanations)

The code to request an extended execution session is simple enough, just a few lines as follow. Keep in mind that you also need to properly deal with the disposal and revocation of extended execution sessions.

```
var session = new ExtendedExecutionSession();
session.Reason = ExtendedExecutionReason.Unspecified;
ExtendedExecutionResult result = await session.RequestExtensionAsync();
if (result == ExtendedExecutionResult.Allowed)
{
    //do your long running task here
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/ExtendedExecution/cs/Scenario1_UnspecifiedReason.xaml.cs) is more complete example that guide you how to request, dispose and deal with the revocation of extended execution sessions.

Comment: Already tested, the application remains alive but the microphone is turned off by the system, so it can't record audio.

Comment: I don’t think OS would turn off microphone if an app is actively using it...it is one of the resources required by the running app. I tested with the built in microphone on my laptop, don’t know if you are using an external one but anyway this should not make a difference.